# Behavior of algebraic functions at critical points (Ahlfors)

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text, page 304, he discusses the critical points of an algebraic function defined by the polynomial $$P(w,z) =a_0(z) w^n+a_1(z)w^{n-1}+ \dots+a_n(z) =0 .$$

He chooses a germ determined by one of the branches $f_i$ at a non-critical point $z_0$, near a fixed critical point $c_k$, and says:

> By the result of Sec. 1.6 we can write
>   $$f_i(z)=\sum_{\nu=-\infty}^\infty A_\nu (z-c_k)^{\nu/h} \tag{5} $$
>   Suppose first that $c_k$ is not a zero of $a_0(z)$. Then $f_i(z)$ remains bounded as $z$ tends to $c_k$. Indeed, as soon as $f_i(z) \neq 0$ the equation $P(f_i(z),z) = 0$ can be written in the form $$a_0(z)+a_1(z) f_i(z)^{-1}+ \dots a_n(z) f_i(z)^{-n}=0 \tag{6} $$
>   If $f_i(z)$ were unbounded, there would exist points $z_n \to c_k$ with $f_i(z_n) \to \infty$. Substitution in (6) would yield $a_0(z_n) \to 0$, contrary to the assumption $a_0(c_k)  \neq 0$. *It follows that the development (5) contains only positive powers, and $f_i$ has at most an ordinary algebraic singularity at $c_k$.*

**My question is:** How does it follow that no negative powers are allowed?

If this was a Laurent development I would have known how to show this, using the classification of isolated singularities of analytic functions. However, for this "Puiseux series" the singular point $c_k$ is not isolated, and I have no idea how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Laurent series

$$g_i(\zeta) = \sum_{\nu = -\infty}^\infty A_\nu \zeta^\nu,$$

and the equation $P(g_i(\zeta), c_k + \zeta^h) = 0$.

Then you are exactly in the situation you know to handle, and note that $g_i(\zeta) = f_i(c_k + \zeta^h)$ (if the branch of the $h$-th root in $(5)$ fits, $f_i(c_k+\zeta^h) = g_i(\omega^m\zeta)$ for some $1\leqslant m < h$ otherwise, cf. [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623459/branch-points-of-global-analytic-functions-ahlfors), where $\omega = \exp (2\pi i/h)$).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but where do I get to choose the branch for the $h$-th root? As far as I can tell, a definite branch is given to me in eq. (5).

Comment: When interpreting the right hand side of $(5)$, you have $h$ possible choices for the branch; one of them leads to $f_i(c_k + \zeta^h) = g_i(\zeta)$, the others to $f_i(c_k+\zeta^h) = g_i(\omega^m\zeta)$, [cf. the previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623459/branch-points-of-global-analytic-functions-ahlfors). Right, the choice of the branch is determined by having both sides of $(5)$ equal, so I should have worded that differently.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, thanks again!

Comment: Hey Daniel. I've finally finished the book, and wanted to thank you for your help. I would be even more thankful if you could assist me with several questions left unanswered. Since they appear hard I will be willing to pay you a bounty for each one. Hope it's not a rude request. Cheers.

Comment: Congrats. I have a couple of tabs open with some of the questions;) These are questions that I can't answer by just reading half a page to see what it is about. Since I've forgotten much of it, I'd have to work myself into it again. In principle, I want to do that, but, you know, time is a scarce resource, so I haven't gotten around to it yet. (Forget about the bounties as far as I'm concerned, though a bounty might of course attract others to answer.)